# Time Complexity of Creating a Binary Tree

Tags: java, tree, time-complexity

I am trying to create a tree from a source that provides: the 2 nodes to be added to the tree, and the node which these 2 news nodes should be added. To find where this node is in the tree, I used a inorder traversal which takes O(n). So if there was n number of nodes to be added in the tree, will the creation of the whole tree be O(n^2). My constraint is that it should only take O(n) to create the tree.

Comment: I really can't see how adding n nodes to a binary tree one after another could be achieved in less than `O(n log n)`. There does seem to be something missing from your description. Also I assume that's homework so you should add the right tags.

Comment: Why do you need an inorder traversal to find the right place in the tree?  The nodes should be arranged in a manner that enables you to find a given node in O(log(n)) average time.  If you can't have such an arrangement, maybe a binary tree is not the right structure for your data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could keep references to each node of the tree in a HashMap [1], to get `O(1)` access to each node instead of the `O(log(n))` which is typical of trees. That would make it possible to build the tree in `O(n)` time, because that HashMap lets you jump directly to a node instead of traversing there from the tree's root node.

[1] The key would be whatever the source uses for uniquely identifying the nodes (I'm assuming it to be an integer or string). The value would be a reference to the node in the tree. Note that the tree implementation must make all its nodes public, so you will probably need to write the tree yourself or find a suitable library (JDK's trees such as TreeMap keep their internal structure private, so they won't cut it).

Comment: while this would solve the question, it begs another question: Why not just store the data in a HashMap at the point and forgo the tree entirely.

Comment: twain249: True. If this is homework, I doubt there is any real reason to use a tree, other than that the assignment says so. :) One realistic (but rare) reason I could come up with is that the system needs to quickly restore its state from a file after restart (thus the O(n) startup time) and during normal operation the system has strict worst-case latency requirements (thus hash map's amortized O(1) is not acceptable, but a tree's predictable O(log(n)) is needed).

Comment: The words **O(1) amortized time given a perfect hash function** or `O(1) average` should appear more predominantly in this answer :-)

Comment: One advantage I can think using a B-tree instead of a hash-table, if you are storing strings, is that with a hash-table you can not do prefix searches, with B-tree you can.

Answer (score 11):

Looking up a node in a binary tree is `O(log(n))` because the tree has `log(n)` levels (each level holds twice as much as the level above it). Therefore to create/insert `n` elements into a binary tree it's `O(nlog(n))`.

Comment: Look ups are only `O(log(n))` if the tree is balanced, `O(n)` if its unbalanced. Create/insert n elements if it's sorted would be `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 1):

for Binary search tree time complexity will be O(nlogn) when the elements are not sorted and sorted it takes O(n^2). It is because to to insert one element in a sorted list in a BST O(n) time is taken so for n elements O(n^2) and for a balanced or almost balanced binary search tree max time for insertion is logn so for n elements it is nlogn